# Why am I getting "TypeError: message must be set" when clicking debug test in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytest

I'm trying to get pytest back up and running in VS Code. I have the simple test function as follows:

```
def test_func():
    x = 1
    y = 1
    assert x == y
```

The test is discovered fine and I can click on the `Run Test` link above the test function to run the test. However, if I click the `Debug Test` link then I get an output message saying `Error: TypeError: message must be set`.

I've tried googling the error and there is only one result (on GitHub) however the link is dead.

Any ideas on what might be happening?

Comment: Does it go away if you give your `assert` a message, i.e. `assert x == y, "x and y must be equal"`?

Comment: Hey. Thanks for responding. I'm now back in ```Test discovery failed``` hell so I can't try anything :( I'll post back as soon as I get back up and running!

Comment: Looks like a possible bug to me, introduced with [this commit](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/c67a82da3aebe7cf002a493296d978bfc05546c3). You could write a bug report for VSCode.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen - thanks. There's a whole heap else wrong besides that. Once I can get to discovering tests again and can reproduce the error I'll log something

Comment: @Jossy There is a similar problem in this [link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/14067) and it has been submitted to Github, we are looking forward to a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug in VSCode. See [this Github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/14067).

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+Shift+P in VsCode then click on "Python: Run All Tests"